# How to manipulate same method with different criteria?

Tags: java, database

I'm working on a java application. I have a scenario as below.

I have a stored procedure to get customer details, I'm passing "areaCode" as a param. This procedure is called from the application using `getCustDetails(areaCode)` method. This method is used more than 100 times in entire application.

i.e. `getCustDetails(areaCode);`
Now my requirements got changed. Now there is a column named "status" in my database table. now I want to get the customer details which has value "active" in their status column.

What is the best way to overcome through this requrements? Should I change the method declaration and method calls to all over the application as given below or is there any other way we can reduce our efforts?

```
getCustDetails(areaCode,status);
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the original method and create a new method:

```
public ReturnType getCustDetails(Type1 areaCode) {
    // Move your code to the new function
    // call the new function
    getCustDetails(areaCode, DEFAULT_STATUS /* Or null */);
}

public ReturnType getCustDetails(Type1 areaCode, Type2 status) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But here it's return the customer details who has DEFAULT_STATUS like "Active or InActive". But my requirement is that in some methods call, i need Active status customers and others need InActive status customers

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to modify existing method, just create a new method `getCustDetails(status)` or `getCustDetails(areaCode,status)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change signature and mass refactor your code
2. Change method body to meet new requirements (very VEEEERY foolish approach because requirements always can changem again
3. If I were you, I would define new method with 2 parameters `getCustDetails(areaCode,status);` and call it when needed. Your `getCustDetails(areaCode);` would simply call new `getCustDetails(areaCode,status);` with status set to null. I think thats the best approach